# Importing Google App Engine App (Java) to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

Firstly: I am not sure if it is a proper place for such question so please move it if you decide that there's more fitting space for it.

I have some GAE based project that I need to import to Eclipse. I downloaded fresh version of Eclipse EE (Kepler) and installed App Engine Plugin. Then I created a new project from sources and tried to configure it... This is where problem starts.

When I try to build project I get 3 errors:

```
The App Engine SDK '\incap-ii\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.0.jar' on the project's build path is not valid (SDK directory 'D:\incap-ii\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.0.jar' does not exist)    incap-ii        Unknown Google App Engine Problem
Project 'incap-ii' is missing required library: 'war/WEB-INF/lib/jsr107cache-1.1.jar'   incap-ii        Build path  Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    incap-ii        Unknown Java Problem
```

First error says that some jar file couldn't be found but the path displayed is strange. Actually it's missing a part directing to the workspace (`D:\workspaces\eclipse GAE\`) - rest, starting from incap-ii is fine. I tried to configure Build Path or change SDK path:

[image: config]

As you can see I have 2 SDK in configuration. However, I cannot change the one used in this project: I pick the appengine-java-1.8.5 - 1.8.5 from the list, click ok, dialog window closes but error still exists and once I open the dialog again I see that the change was not saved (still uses the wrong one).

Is there some specific configuration somewhere that I should change??

[EDIT]
Some more explanation/screes (below). As you can seen at screen no.1 I (preferences\google\appengine) I have configured 2 appEgines: the one I downloaded and extracted manually (checked on screen) and second one that was downloaded by Google App Engine Plugin. Anyway, when I check the project preferences now I see 3 engines (screen 2) - the additional one (selected) is in the project dir. As I said I cannot change that because after I click "ok" the changes aren't saved. However though, when I open "configure SDKs" (screen 3) I can see just the two external engines. What the hell? I tried to reinstall whole Eclipse but it did not help... also, I am able to run this project with AppEngine downloaded manually when I build it with Netbeans and run from shell so the engine is probably fine...

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

Answer (score 11):

An issue I encountered was probably the same as yours. In my case, Eclipse said:

> The App Engine SDK
>   'C:\Users\Takahiko.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.8.8\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.8.jar'
>   on the project's build path is not valid (SDK location
>   'C:\Users\Takahiko.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.8.8\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.8.jar'
>   is not a directory)

This implies that Eclipse found App Engine SDK binaries in the local maven repository (~/.m2/repository) *before* it searched the installation directory of App Engine SDK.

**(1) Close your project** in Eclipse.

**(2) Open .classpath** of your project with a text editor and if it contains classpathentry's related to App Engine like the following:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/shared/appengine-local-runtime-shared.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/shared/el-api.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/shared/jsp/repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/shared/jsp/repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/shared/jsp/repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/shared/jsp/repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/shared/jsp/repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/shared/jsp-api.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/shared/servlet-api.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/appengine-tools-api.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/opt/user/appengine-api-labs/v1/appengine-api-labs.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/opt/user/appengine-endpoints/v1/appengine-endpoints-deps.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/opt/user/appengine-endpoints/v1/appengine-endpoints.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/asm-4.0.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/jta-1.1.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/opt/user/jsr107/v1/appengine-jsr107cache-1.8.8.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/opt/user/jsr107/v1/jsr107cache-1.1.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/lib/user/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.8.jar" sourcepath="C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/src/user/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.8-src.zip">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="file:/C:/Eclipse/eclipse-juno/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8/docs/javadoc/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

**(3) Remove all the classpathentry's** (related to App Engine jar files).

**(4) Add GAE_CONTAINER** *before* MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER.

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.GAE_CONTAINER"/>
```

**(5) Reopen your project**.

Comment: Worked for me perfectly - strange but Thanks anyway :)

Comment: To get the .classpath file to show up in my eclipse package view, from the Package Explorer view, I had to select the small drop down arrow-> filters -> deselect all. Note: I really don't want to have anything hidden, so you can be more selective than that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a problem with the configuration of your SDK.

Your screenshot shows the configuration of your project, but I think you need to look at preferences --> google --> app engine, and check the configuration of your SDK's there.  I think it is likely that the one you can't select for your project will show an error there, but either way you will probably want to remove and re-add it and make sure its path is valid.

Comment: Of your several GAE SDK installations, the one that is 'normal' (in my experience) is the one in Eclipse/plugins folder.  I believe that is the one that came bundled with the GPE.  Are you able to select that one for your project?

Comment: The one that came with plugin is App Engine 1.8.5. As I said: I can choose it from select but when I close the dialog with ok change is not saved. I also have GAE downloaded from https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Java but cannot pick it (so that it is actually used) neither.